# Move unique_ptr ownership from one class to another

Tags: c++, c++11, move

I want to create a unique pointer in one class, class A, then pass on the ownership to another class, class B. Am I ok doing such a thing?

The code below gives me error in getC:
`error: call to deleted constructor of 'std::unique_ptr<C>`

What am I doing wrong?

```
class A {
...
  void func(shared_ptr<B> Bptr) {
   A_pass = make_unique<C>();
   Bptr->setPass(move(A_pass));
  }
  unique_ptr<C> getC()
  {
    return A_pass;
  }
 unique_ptr<C> A_pass;
};

class B {
...
 void setPass(unique_ptr<C> pass_ptr){
  B_pass = move(pass_ptr);
 }
 unique_ptr<C> B_pass;
}
```

edit: update the question

Comment: You may realize that in `A::func`,  the assignment To `A_pass` is unnecessary... you could just pass in the result of `make_unique<C>()` directly.

Comment: class C definition is not relevant except for the fact that I cant construct unique_ptr to it in class B directly due to circular dependency between B and C. The 'dots' are also not relevant

Comment: _Something_ in those dots and/or `C` is relevant because there's nothing wrong with the code shown here.  Please expand your question to include a [mcve] that we can paste into our own compiler to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I updated the question with function `getC` which is the line giving the error.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable.  It wouldn't be unique if it was.  `getC` is trying to return a copy of `A_pass`.

Comment: If a class is used in your example code but the exact definition is not relevant, you should provide a stub definition, as in `class C {};`. This makes your error *reproducible*. On the flip side, it looks like you could make your code shorter by dropping the definitions of the class `B` and of the member function `func`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not state where the compiler error occurs, but I would guess it’s the `getC()` member function:

```
class A {
...
 
  unique_ptr<C> getC()
  {
    return A_pass;
  }
 unique_ptr<C> A_pass;
};
```

The function as written is attempting to copy `A_pass`, which of course is not possible for the `std::unique_ptr<T>` type.

You can rewrite it to explicitly move from the source (I’m not able to test this):

```
unique_ptr<C> A::getC() {
    return A_pass.release();
    // alternative: return unique_ptr<C>(std::move(A_pass));
}
```